# VisualStudio 2017 refactor doesnt work for F#

Tags: visual-studio, f#, refactoring, visual-studio-2017

I have project in `F#`, i'm working on `VisualStudio2017`. I tried to refactor the code and use inline, but this menu item is unavailable. Also when i click *Rename* nothing happened.

- Why it is unavailable?
- How to force *refactor* operation to work?

[image]

```
let blobToBlobWithInfo (b:IListBlobItem ) = 
    try
        let blobUri = b.Uri.ToString()
        let blobUriParts = blobUri.Split '/'
        let t = Array.length blobUriParts
        let integrationName =  blobUriParts.[t-2]
        if(integrationName <> "LogsToBlobService") then
            let logTime = new System.DateTime( System.Int32.Parse <| blobUriParts.[t-1].Substring(0,4), System.Int32.Parse <|blobUriParts.[t-1].Substring(4,2), System.Int32.Parse <|blobUriParts.[t-1].Substring(6,2))
            Some((b,integrationName,logTime))
        else
            None
    with
        | :? System.ArgumentException -> None
        | _ -> None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in Visual Studio 2017.

It will be fixed in Update 2.

It's confirmed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2833).

Answer (score 2):

Is that Resharper's refactoring or VS2017's proper? If you just want to rename you can update the Visual F# Tools to the latest version from myget (which will be included in the VS update referenced in the answer):
https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/wiki/Using-Nightly-Releases-of-the-Visual-F%23-Tools.

For example renaming csv to csv2 inline:

[image]

[image]

*Update with latest version of VF# Tools:*

[image]

You can also download it from here:
https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/fsharp/package/vsix/VisualFSharp

Comment: Visual F# Tools doesn't support Visual studio 2017 at this moment

>Works with Visual Studio 2013, 2015

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FSharpSoftwareFoundation.VisualFPowerTools

Comment: @burzhuy You're not wrong, but that is the old Visual F# Power Tools. That has been depreciated. Now F# tools is built into VS2017. However the version you get is a bit old due to the code freeze for VS2017 RTW. Hence you should enable the myget feed and install the latest build of the VS F# Tools. I'll add a screenshot with my version.

Comment: Thanks ,but answer was useful only for 50%! Nonetheless upvote for you! I have updated F# power tools, but rename is the only one operation that is working now. 'inline' is stil unavailable.