# Why can't I get Suave to work on VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, suave

I saw a video on https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-F-Tools where a project using Suave is created. I tried to follow exactly what was being done but my installation of VS 2017, just updated today, behaves quite differently.

First I installed Suave exactly like in the video, and it appears among my references, between `mscorlib` and `System`, just like in the video.

Then the video shows the following code:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    startWebServer
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

At this point VS 2017 suggests "Open Suave" in the video, since startWebServer is not recognized. I copied the same code in my editor, in the file `Program.fs`. There is an error message "The value or constructor 'startWebServer' is not defined" but there are no suggestions when the cursor hovers on the left yellow area. (Maybe that is because I am using Community Edition?)

In any case, I added `open Suave` to the code so I had:

```
open Suave

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    startWebServer
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

At this point I get a red squiggle under Suave and the error message "The namespace or module 'Suave' is not defined."

If I right-click on Suave in the Solution Explorer and then choose "Send to Interactive" then I can open `Suave` in F# Interactive.

I can install and use other packages like Deedle with no problems.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Could you post your `.fsproj` file to a Gist or pastebin, and then link it from your question? It might be that the reference is somehow incorrect. Another thing to try is [installing the nightly builds of the Visual F# Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/14/announcing-nightly-releases-for-the-visual-f-tools/): "**it is highly recommended that you install the latest nightly.** There have been a number of bug fixes, performance improvements, and new features that make the overall experience better than what was made available at the VS 2017 release." (Emphasis in original)

Comment: @rmunn - Thanks for looking into this. The link to the gist is https://gist.github.com/Soldalma/7828306736cb393ba38f4bb14f752b11

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with it at first glance. What happens if you install a nightly build of the Visual F# Tools? Does that fix it? I know the version of Visual F# Tools that was released with the final Visual Studio release had some bugs that were quickly fixed in a nightly build, but I don't know the details. So that's my next suggestion. If that doesn't work, then try installing VS Code and Ionide, and see if Ionide handles it where Visual Studio doesn't. All of these things will give us more data points to use in trying to figure out a solution to your problem.

Comment: @rmunn - I had already tried to install a nightly build after experiencing this problem. It did not help. As for VS Code, I am interested in it but it does not have a Solution Explorer like VS, so I would have to first learn how to tell it about my project's structure, which at this point I don't know how to do. (Any tips on where to learn it?)

Comment: @rmunn - One thing I noticed is that I don't have autocomplete in VS 2017. For example, if I enter `type FooBar = | Foo of` I don't get suggestions. I saw videos where VS 2017 has that feature. Maybe this means my VS 2017 is not up to date, how do I check it?

Comment: If you're not getting autocomplete, then something is wrong with your Visual F# Tools installation. I don't use Visual Studio for F# development since I do most of my dev work on Linux, so I can't tell you exactly what to look for -- but it sounds like your problem is primarily caused by "something is wrong with your Visual F# Tools installation". So maybe the Extensions menu (wherever it's found in VS) is the place to start.

Comment: @Soldalma you should certainly have auto-complete in F# in VS2017. If I type `Foo of s` and hit space, it will show me string. You can check the version of your F# Tools by going into Tools | Extensions. Under Installed | Tools you will see Visual F# Tools [Experimental] and othe right the installed date and Version (e.g. 15.4.1.17041701). Can you post a screenshot of that?

Comment: by the way, and I'm not sure what F# Core version Suave needs or expects, but you're referencing F#4.0:  `<HintPath>..\packages\FSharp.Core.4.0.0.1\lib\net40\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>`, however you're targeting F# 4.1: `<TargetFSharpCoreVersion>4.4.1.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>`.

Comment: I think this is due to some mismatch of what Suave expects (F# 4.0) and what VS2017 (F# 4.1) rather than your VS setup.

Comment: @s952163 - It says the installed date is 3/8/2017 and the version is 15.4.1.17022502. I got a screenshot but I don't know how to post it.

Comment: You should certainly update it. :) Can you refer to my answer in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402467/visualstudio-2017-refactor-doesnt-work-for-f) on installing the nightly release of the VF# Tools. Regarding your specific Suave issue, see below. If you're at it add `Paket` as well.

Comment: Regarding the screenshots, it's quite useful, you can click on `Edit` for your own question. Then just pick the Add Image Icon (some mountain I believe), if you doubleclick on the middle of the tool thatit will let you add a png file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you can but it might be just a little work:

[image]

You should be able to clone [my repo](https://github.com/s952163/Suave2.git) if necessary. You will note that my fsprojects file does not reference an explicit version of FSharp.Core so there is no confusion between the Target and actual version. It's actually FSharp.Core 4.1 btw.

If you're working from your original solution I would make a new one first.

1. Set the project to .NET 4.6.2 (or whatever you fancy)
2. Target F# 4.1
3. Nuget Suave

Add this point nuget will download FSharp.Core and replace it in your project. That's not very nice.

4. Delete FSharp.Core from your references
5. From Nuget add FSharp.Core 4.1

You're good to go:

[image]

I also suggest you install [Paket](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteffenForkmann.PaketforVisualStudio) for VS2017. You can then access it from the Tools menu in VS. That way you can just add Suave and FSharp.core to your paket.references and dependencies file, set `redirects: on`, run Paket install from the menu and forget about all this version mismatch business. If you're using a lot of fsx files, this is extra nice because paket will strip out the version numbers from the path.  Please look at the paket.dependencies and paket.references file in the solution on GitHub:

paket.dependencies in solution root:

```
framework: = net462
source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
redirects: on

nuget Suave
```

paket.references in project folder:

```
Suave
FSharp.Core
```

Comment: I managed to make it work. First I installed `Paket` and pasted the code you provided on `paket.dependencies` and `paket.references`. That did not work. Then I right-clicked on the project name in Solution Explorer, then on Properties, and I noticed that the .NET Framework was version 4.5.2. I changed it to version 4.6.2 and the red squigglies below `Suave` in `open Suave` disappeared. I noticed that I cannot change the Target F# runtime, which is greyed out and fixed at 4.4.1.0 (I thought it would be 4.0 or 4.1). In any case, many thanks.

Comment: Just changing the .Net Framework to 4.6.2 worked for me.

Comment: Just changing .Net Framework to 4.6.2 was also sufficient for me.