# Add Suave - Open Declarations not working

Tags: f#, package, suave

I add Suave.io to my project - so far empty - via NuGet and that's alright. But none of the `open Suave` declarations work yielding "The namespace or module "Suave" is not defined."
The following works in script file though:

```
#r ".../Suave.dll"
open Suave
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Targeting .NET 4.7 (rather than 4.5.2) solved the issue. Wierd

Comment: most probably Suave pulled down and older version of FSharp.Core: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460879/why-cant-i-get-suave-to-work-on-vs-2017/43464238