# Why adding some packages breaks my code?

Tags: f#, nuget, package

I noticed that adding packages sometimes breaks my code. Functions like `Seq.replicate` and `List.take` that were working get red squiggly lines and the program no longer runs. Here is a detailed procedure that should replicate the problem (I am using `VS Community Edition 2017`):

1) Create a project.

2) `Program.fs` contains the code:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

3) Add two lines of code as follows:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let repla = Seq.replicate 10 "A"
    printfn "%A" (repla |> List.ofSeq |> List.take 5)
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

3) Hit `Ctrl+F5`, the program runs without any problems.

4) Right-click on `References` on the `Solution Explorer`. Click on `Manage Nuget Packages...`.

5) Click on `Browse`.

6) Search for `Newtonsoft.Json` and install it.

7) Hit `Ctrl+F5`, the program runs without any problems. The console prints

```
["A"; "A"; "A"; "A"; "A"]
[||]
```

8) Proceed as in steps 4 to 6 and install package `MathNet.Numerics` using `Nuget`.

9) Hit `Ctrl+F5`, the program runs without any problems. The console prints

`["A"; "A"; "A"; "A"; "A"]
[||]`

10) Proceed as in steps 4 to 6 and install package `MathNet.Numerics.FSharp` using `Nuget`.

11) Click on the `Program.fs` tab. The dreaded red squiggly lines appeared under Seq.replicate`and`List.take`.

12) Hit `Ctrl+F5`. A dialog box pops up with the following message:

```
There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?
```

Questions:

a) What exactly is happening?

b) Is this an isolated case related to a problem in `MathNet.Numerics.FSharp` or the specific combination of packages installed, or the order in which they were installed? Or is this a common problem?

c) Is it possible to avoid this problem while using Nuget?

d) If not, is it possible to avoid this problem by installing by some other means (not Nuget)?

Comment: What versions of the packages are you installing?

Comment: (1) What is the error under the red squiggly? (2) Have you noticed if installing `MathNet.Numerics.FSharp` has caused any _other_ packages to be installed (due to being transitive dependencies)?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - The error under the red squiggly is `The value, constructor, namespace or type 'replicate'is not defined`. When `MathNet.Numerics.FSharp` is installed it also installs `FSharp.Core.3.1.2.5`.

Comment: @mydogisbox - `MathNet.Numerics` and `MathNet.Numerics.FSharp` are both version `3.19.0`. `Newtonsoft.Json` is version `10.0.3` but the problem occurs even if I do not install it. The answer by `FuleSnabel` shows that the problem is due to shifting to `FSharp.Core.3.1.2.5`, an older version of `FSharp.Core` .

Comment: @Soldalma I added an answer that shows you how to do this w/o going deep into the bowels of fsproj, and also expanded on Paket. Hope you will give it another try, because it can be used from the command line as well, and also in VSCode.

Comment: the docs are always a good place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/  I added some other comments below the answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think the OP's concerns are somewhat valid. I would discourage hand-editing the fsproj file. And also the comments are very valid too, Paket is a great tool that can simplify dependency management both in VS and Code. So here's a very simple, two part answer, where a) you can actually get your solution working using nugget and without hand-editing the project file, and b) get a quick intro to how using paket on VS.

This issue where some package downloads and old dependency that messes up other code occurs now and then and is probably due to a strategy of relying on the minimum viable version. Your issue is somewhat similar to this Q: [Why can't I get suave to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460879/why-cant-i-get-suave-to-work-on-vs-2017/43464238).

Here's the simplest solution using just nugget:

1. Open a new solution with an fsharp console project
2. At this point your Fsharp.Core in VS2017 will be 4.1:

[image]

3. Now add Mathnet.Numerics.Fsharp via nugget:

[image]

Now, very unfortunately you got downgraded to F# 3.1

4. This is no good, so just get Fsharp.Core via nugget as well!

[image]

5. And voila, you're back to a working solution without needing to edit fsproj. Basically all you had to do is add the Fsharp.Core package. You could have also changed the .NET Framework option in properties and move it to .NET 4.7 with Fsharp 4.1:

[image]

Now for Part 2 of the answer with Paket (btw, the Paket plugin just got updated and I tested and it works fine). You can essentially use it as a replacement for nugget or directly edit the files. You actually need to work with two files, `paket.dependencies` in the solution root and `paket.references` in the project root. `Paket.lock` will be generated. Here's a two-step process to get started. Take the project you just made above and from the Tools menu in VS select `Paket Dependencies Manager`, do `Initialize Paket`, then do `Convert From Nuget`:

[image]

With this you can keep managing your dependencies with nuget or use paket if you like. Next I will add Newtonsoft.JSON to the references. Double-click on the `paket.dependencies` file and add the following line: `nuget Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3 restriction: >= net452` , you only actually need Newtonsoft.Json in there but we don't want to download the whole interweb called .NetCore. Also add this line to `paket.references` (you can just click on it in the project explorer): `Newtonsoft.Json`. And the run Tools | Paket | Install:

Paket.dependencies:

[image]

Paket.references:

[image]

And Run Paket Install:

[image]

And you will have Newtonsoft.JSON installed. Usually you don't need to specify a version of framework restriction, however it has some pre-release package that you might not want, and also I assume you don't need the .netcore dependencies.

You can actually right click and try install this package from the references Add Package menu, but you will bump into dependency errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Superb. I looked carefully at the first part of your answer and of course everything works as you said. But I am a bit confused about the last sentence: "You could have also changed the .NET Framework option in properties and move it to .NET 4.7 with Fsharp 4.1" I opened the project properties and saw a page like the one in your post. But both in my screen and in the page you posted it had ".NET Framework 4.5.2" and you mentioned ".NET 4.7". Please don't mind if this is a silly question. I am learning.

Comment: On Part 2 of the answer, I understand that Paket is in many ways better than the already excellent Nuget. But I had to reinstall VS three times after getting in trouble with Paket as I did not have the knowledge to deal with the issues I was facing. I would like to try what you are suggesting but it would be easier if there was a way to uninstall Paket without having to uninstall and reinstall VS in case things do not work as expected. Is that possible? Could I use Git/Bitbucket (that is what I use) to do that?

Comment: u don't need to use paket if u don't want to. i.e. it's not a requirenment. paket is just an exe, you can delete the .paket folder any time. You can also uninstall the VS paket add-in from the Tools menu in VS.

Comment: re: .Net framework, there are various versions of the .Net Base Class Libraries, 4.6, 4.7. In the properties page u can select which version to target. you can also select which F# Core to target. I believe you can target 4.6.x in VS2017, and you would need to install the 4.7 targeting pack to use that. these are all backwards compatible versions but include big fixes and new methods, for example unix time in DateTime appeared in 4.6.

Answer (score 6):

`MathNet.Numerics.FSharp` has a dependency to `FSharp.Core.3.1.2.5` which replaces the current version of `FSharp.Core` you are using. Being quite old `3.1.2.5` lacks many functions.

This happens with other popular `F#` libraries such as `FsCheck` as well. I usually change the reference to the newest version of `FSharp.Core`as that should be backward compatible.

To do so I unload the `F#` project and update the `FSharp.Core` reference in the project file to:

```
<Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
  <Name>FSharp.Core</Name>
  <AssemblyName>FSharp.Core.dll</AssemblyName>
  <HintPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion)\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Then I reload the project.

As this is a rather clunky procedure hopefully more insightful users will post a better solution.

Comment: Clunky or not it worked. Many thanks. Is there a book/PDF/link that teaches a beginner how to deal with project files?

Comment: @Soldalma use paket ;-) http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/  Paket checks all this stuff for you and allows you to be explicit about dependencies.

Comment: @mydogisbox - For me that is not the way. I tried Paket and had to reinstall VS Studio 2017 to get rid of it. Same type of problems, but worse. Maybe it is because I don't know how to use it. The error messages issued by Paket were incomprehensible to me. I could not find instructions for a beginner that knows little about projects, build, etc. Also, using Paket one has to deal with three file, with Nuget it is only one.

Comment: @Soldalma I also had problems with getting it setup initially.  The work to understand it was definitely worth the effort.

Comment: @Soldalma - *Also, using Paket one has to deal with three file, with Nuget it is only one.* Once you learn why Paket separates the concepts into three files, you'll be complaining about this in the other direction: "Why does NuGet conflate things into a single file when they should **clearly** be separated into different files?" :-) Being able to commit your `paket.lock` file and know that all the others devs are going to get **exactly** the same versions of the dependencies when they run `paket restore` is great for one's peace of mind, for example.